# Angular onEnter ui.router method not work how expect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `Angular` app and its `ui.router` module have an `onEnter` method. I want to call function when state menu item is clicked and state is changed. But now my app is not working correctly. E.g. I go to `app.com/what` and console print all 5 lines when app is loaded, and after that nothing is printed after menu click is clicked. I read this [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks)

> There are also optional 'onEnter' and 'onExit' callbacks that get called when a state becomes active and inactive respectively.

my console when page loaded:

```
[debug] changeMenu item_id:1495
[debug] changeMenu item_id:1342
[debug] changeMenu item_id:1344
[debug] changeMenu item_id:1346
[debug] changeMenu item_id:1346
```

My goal is call `changeMenu` function only when menu item is clicked or on `init` step.

```
          var changeMenu = function(itemID){
              console.log("[debug] changeMenu item_id:"+itemID);
              // for menu css
              $("#nav_menu li.active").removeClass("active");
              $("#nav_menu li#menu-item-"+itemID).addClass('active');
              $('#nav_menu').spasticNav();
          }
          //
          // Now set up the states
          $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
              url: "/",
              templateUrl: "main.html",
              onEnter: changeMenu(1495)
            })
            .state('what', {
              url: "/what",
              templateUrl: "what.html",
              onEnter: changeMenu(1342)
            })
            .state('where', {
              url: "/where",
              templateUrl: "where.html",
              onEnter: changeMenu(1344)

            })
            .state('cost_rent', {
              url: "/cost_rent",
              templateUrl: "cost_rent.html",
              onEnter: changeMenu(1346)

            })
            .state('cost_sell', { 
              url: "/cost_sell",
              templateUrl: "cost_sell.html",
              onEnter: changeMenu(1346)
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use onEnter, it expects a closure(callback function).`onEnter: changeMenu(1495)` is not a callback function, it execute the function, which is why all 5 debug messages show altogether. so what you can do is something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "main.html",
    onEnter: function() {
      changeMenu(1495);
    }
  })
```